# which of the charges go to the airport and which charges go the govt.?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, fees-and-charges, qatar-airways, mumbai

I recently went for an international flight from Mumbai to Cape Town with a 24 hour layover in Qatar, South Africa and back via Qatar Airways by the same route. While I was booking I was told/given the various charges. Am curious to know which ones get passed on to the airport, which to the carrier and which go to the Government -

Fuel Surcharge (YQAC)   17024.00

Fiscal Tax (YRVB)    536.00

Service Tax (JNAD)  2779.00

Development Fee (YMDE)  825.00

User Development Fee (INDO) 628.00

Passenger Service Fee (WOMU)    149.00

```
                            100.00

                            274.00
```

Passenger Service Charge (PZSE)     274.00

Passenger Safety Charge (EVAB)  90.00

Passenger Service Charge (ZAEB)     1529.00

Service Security Charge (UMSE)  106.00

Air Passenger Tax (WCTR)    840.00

Now I'm guessing the Air fuel surcharge and the Air Passenger Tax would be going to the Central or/and State Govt. Can anybody help ? Also the airport charges are with the airport of origin or would it be distributed with other airports which I used/travelled to as well ? How is the whole thing calculated ?

umm... can somebody share why they want to close this question ?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: You have to consider many Airport Terminals are operated by Government agencies.  Also, and 'airport' is actually a number of separate business/entities and that are structured differently.

Comment: I need to know as a new airport has just come up nearby, I'm trying to figure out some rough off-the-back-envelope calculations to figure out how much time it would take to have the original (capital) written down to zero.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about figuring out how long it takes to pay off an airport.

Comment: The back of the envelope calculation doesn't really work here, since the airport also receives revenue from the airlines and other tenants (for things like rent and landing fees) that isn't listed as a separate charge on your ticket but is part of the base fare. Nor does this give you any idea of the airport's expenses. You'd need to look at a copy of the airport's budget for that kind of calculation, not the fees on a single air ticket.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, the "fuel surcharge" goes to the carrier, anything labeled "tax" goes to a government entity, items labeled "passenger" go to the airport authority, "development" items could go to airport or local government.

But determining which specific charges apply to your nearby airport would mean unraveling the four letter code attached to each, as the ticket price contains fees, taxes and service charges for all the airports involved.

Comment: any idea where I could find this info. ?

Comment: Ask Qatar Airways.

Comment: @shirish You can [buy it for 4049 USD](http://www.iata.org/publications/store/Pages/list-of-ticket-and-airport-taxes-and-fees.aspx).